# Is EEVEE the GLSL engine?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I heard a while back they were making a GLSL engine. Is this the same thing as the upcoming EEVEE engine they're working on for 2.8?

Comment: I don't think it is GLSL based, but I really don't know. I'm basing my opinion on this in a 2.8 dev blog: "**Port Cycles materials to the Eevee engine:**
Port Cycles GLSL code to PyNode"

Comment: I did read that too but didn't know if that meant it wasn't GLSL based. Thanks!